# Data structure alignment in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, alignment, structure

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and struct alignment member value is set to default(/Zp8). Project is being build on 64 bit mode.

```
struct x{
    char e;
    double f;
    double g;
};
```

`sizeof(x)` has returned 24 which is correct as it's a multiple of 8. But for the below structure with same struct alignment value

```
struct x{
    char e;
    long f;
    long g;
};
```

`sizeof(x)` is returning 12 which is not a multiple of 8. I am confused by this.

Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

The `/Zp` switch in Visual C++ does not force the alignment of each member to be 8-bytes.

The alignment of each member is the *minimum* of it's natural alignment and the packing setting provided by `/Zp`.

This is covered in lots of detail on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx)